# IFS nested with multiple text variants to return 1 value

Tags: google-sheets

We were able to get a few formulas working seperately but cannot seem to tie them together. Here are a few:

```
=IFS(AND(OR(C2="Approved",D2="Approved",E2="Approved",B2="Approved"),B15="Rejected")," ")

=IF(AND(OR(C2="Approved",D2="Approved",E2="Approved",B2="Approved"),B15="Approved"),"Approved","Rejected"

=IF(AND(B2="Rejected",C2="Rejected",D2="Rejected",E2="Rejected"),"Rejected","Approved")
```

We want to be able to tie them together with every variation. Here is an example of the table we are working with:

[image]

- If one selection is approved the final decision should be left blank
- If multiple selections are approved but the selection in column B is rejected then the final decision should be left blank
- If multiple selections including the one in column B are approved then the final decision should be approved
- If all selections are rejected the final decision should be rejected
- If all selections are approved the final decision should be approved

We spent hours trying to figure this out and couldn't figure out a way to connect the formulas together. Any help we can get is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(C2="Approved",
           D2="Approved",
           E2="Approved",
           B2="Approved"),
        B15="Rejected"), ,
 IF(AND(OR(C2="Approved",
           D2="Approved",
           E2="Approved",
           B2="Approved"),
        B15="Approved"), "Approved",
 IF(AND(B2="Rejected", 
        C2="Rejected",
        D2="Rejected",
        E2="Rejected"), "Rejected", "Approved")))
```